# Como separar um sistema web com API em domínios?

Tags: php, laravel

Supondo que eu tenha que desenvolver 1 aplicativo e 2 painéis, o aplicativo mobile é alimentado por uma api desenvolvida em php (que é gerenciada por um desses painéis), e o outro painel faz conexão com o aplicativo. Os 2 painéis são web.

**Exemplo:**

O usuário loga no aplicativo e faz check-in na barbearia, a barbearia controla seus clientes pelo painel e eu administro os 2 pelo meu painel.

**Dúvidas:**

A API e os 2 painéis podem ser desenvolvidos no mesmo projeto do laravel  sendo acessados separadamente por subdomínio ou é melhor desenvolver e hospedar cada um separadamente?

É seguro utilizar o mesmo domínio para vários sistemas, levando em conta que será utilizado pagamentos?

Comment: Pode colocar tudo junto, o Laravel possui uma opção de domínio no seu roteador. Se o resto for seguro, o domínio pouco importa

Answer (score 1):

O tipo de aplicação que você está desenvolvendo é multi tenant.

Tem um tutorial de como criar (inglês) -> https://blog.usejournal.com/writing-a-full-featured-multi-tenant-laravel-app-from-scratch-a0e1a7350d9d

Dê uma boa pesquisada no assunto, para entender realmente como funciona!

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel tem 4 tipos de rotas: WEB, API, Console e Channel, ao usar a web é o padrão para acessar as rotas via browser a rota API é para você usar o prefix /api antes de cada requisição e assim ele separa rotas da web com a API assim consegue usar tanto dados no sistema e um aplicativo.

Exemplo: http://dominio.com.br/api/clientes.

No exemplo ele ta retornando todos os clientes via API e usará dessa forma no seu aplicativo claro que tem o Auth:api que é autenticação do Laravel das apis que é um Api_token que ele pede pra você gerar para permitir o acesso aos dados da API, também tem o JWT(Json Web Token) que é muito utilizado no Laravel.

Espero ter te ajudado em algo qualquer dúvida comente ai.